# Regex, match keys in JSON-like object

Tags: json, regex

I have a JSON-like object:

```
{
id: "111",
lat: 22.2223,
lng: 4.22354,
city: "CITY",
address: "Address",
postal: "0000 AA",
phone: "000-0000000",
name: "name",
state: "",
country: "Nederland",
fax: "",
email: "",
monday: "Vanaf 1 februari: 11.00 - 17.30",
tuesday: "09:30 - 17:30",
wednesday: "09:30 - 17:30",
thursday: "09:30 - 17:30",
"friday": "09:30 - 20:00",
saturday: "09:30 - 17:00",
sunday: "gesloten",
extra_sundays: "",
"display": "true",
showonmaplink: "true",
appointment_after_6: "false",
url: "https://www.website.com",

additional_info: ""
}
```

I want to find all the keys of this "object" in order to add quotes where required. For now I use this regex:

```
 (['"])?([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(['"])?:\s
```

It matches all the keys, but also unnecessary words  like `februari`
I tried a lot of different ways to exclude februari, but didn't find right solution.

Please help, how can I exclude the second occurrence of `\w+: ? \s` I used to exclude "https://www.website.com" - maybe you can also advice better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how complex your key names can be, you can match from the beginning of each line until the first colon (`:`):

```
^"?(.+?)"?:
```

What each token means:

```
^     - beginning of line
"?    - match the quotation character zero or 1 time
(.+?) - match one or more character, non-greedy (the `?`)
"?    - match the quotation character zero or 1 time
:     - match the colon character
```

[Stub](https://regex101.com/r/gL9nR6/1). This won't work if your key names contains escaped colons or double quotes, in which case you need more sophisticated regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, basically the aim of the regex was to match keys of this crappy JSON and fix them with quotes. validJson.replace(/^"?(.+?)"?:/gm, '"$1": ');